# Area of the grey region in the following triangle

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, triangles, area

> $ABC$ is a triangle having area of $240$.
>
> Given that $BD:DF:FC=3:4:3$; $BE:EA=5:7$ ; $CG:GA=2:7$ then what is the area of the grey region?
>
> [image: ABC is a triangle having area of 240]

I am not getting any way to start this question, any hint on the theorem will be helpful.

Comment: I dont know how to start this, i know the properties for lines parallel to a side of triangle dividing in some ratios but in this case they are not parallel.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\frac{S_\Delta{BED}}{S_\Delta ABC}=\frac{5\cdot3}{12\cdot10}=\frac{1}{8};$$

$$\frac{S_\Delta{GFC}}{S_\Delta ABC}=\frac{2\cdot3}{9\cdot10}=\frac{1}{15}$$
Thus, $$S_{AEDFG}=240\left(1-\frac{1}{8}-\frac{1}{15}\right)=194.$$

Comment: can you please explain how you did this? did you establish bed and abc are similar triangles?

Comment: @swapedoc It was typo. See now.

Comment: A little explanation around this might be quite nice

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg Can you please give a little explanation on the property used to calculate ratio of areas

Comment: I dont find BED and ABC as similar ie ED not parallel AC similarly GF is not parallel AB

Comment: Nvm understood .You used 1/2 AB*BC sin B

Comment: The idea is the same as mine below. Let h be the height of triangle ABC from C. $A_{ABC}=0.5*AB*h$ and  $A_{EBC}=0.5*EB*h$ hence  $A_{EBC}=EB/AB * A_{ABC}$. Similarly $A_{EBD}=DB/CB * A_{EBC}$, and then you get Michael's formulas...

Answer (score 1):

Let H be the point of (BC) s.t. (AH) // (ED)

You can find the ratio of BD/BH, hence the area of BAH (which has the same height from A than ABC).

Then you can calculate the area of BED which is a triangle similar to BAH.

You can find the area of GFC in the same way.

The answer is Area ABC - Area BED - Area GFC.

Comment: i am sorry i am not getting you BED lets say = x ABH (as they are similar) 
Lets say I take another point T on BC such that AT//GF and GFC = yATC. (as they will be similar) but T and G are not same !.Then how will the solution be possible